# Local martingale and integral condition

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, martingales

Suppose $M^i_t = X^i_t - X^i_0 - \int_0^t b_i(s,X)\, ds$ where $b_i:[0,\infty)\times \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ is a progressively measurable functional and $X^i_t: C[0,\infty)^d \to \mathbb{R}$ ( $X(t\omega)$is a continuous function in $t$

**The question is**: Show that if $M^i_t$ is  a continuous local martingale then

$$\mathbb{P} \bigg[\int_0^t |b_i(s,X)|\, ds < \infty; 0 \leq t <\infty \bigg] = 1$$

I tried the following: Let $E$ be the expectional set $E = \bigg[\omega:\int_0^{t_0} |b_i(s,\omega)|\, ds = \infty \text{ for some } t_0 >0 \bigg]$. If $P(E) >0$ then $M^i_t$ is not a local martingale.

To be a local martingale means that there is a sequence of stopping times $\tau_n$ ($\tau_n \to \infty$ almost surely) such that $M^i_{t \wedge \tau_n}$ is a martingale.

The idea is to show that on the set $E$, $\tau_n < t_0$.
 This I think would be easier if $b_i>0$ but in the case where there is a an absolute value, I can't quite show that the sequence diverges and that the condition $M^i_{t\wedge \tau_n} \in \mathbb{R}$ forces $\tau_n < t_0$

thanks for your help

for reference: this is used in proposition 4.6 (chapter 5 pg 315) of Karatzas and Schreve - Brownian motion and Stochastic calculus

Comment: I don't understand your question. The condition $$\mathbb{P} \left[ \int_0^t |b_i(s,X)| \,ds < \infty; t \geq 0 \right]=1$$ is necessary to **define** $M_t^i$. How can you talk about $M_t^i$ (being a locale martingale) if you don't even know that the integral $\int_0^t b_i(s,X) \, ds$ exists?

Comment: Me neither, but if you look up at reference I gave, they only ask $b_i$ to be progressively measurable. Maybe  the condition $\mathbb{P}\bigg[\int_0^t |b_i(s,X)|\, ds < \infty \bigg] = 1$ is implicit in the statement $M^i_t$ is a local martingale. Still I appreciate some though on that lines

Comment: It's indeed like that: Since $M$ is a (locale) martingale, it is in particular well-defined and therefore $\mathbb{P}[\dots]=1$.